# ContainsRune giving strange results

Tags: unicode, utf-8, go

I'm running this code in Go Playground:

```
fmt.Println(strings.ContainsRune("\xa0", '\xa0'))
```

I'm wondering, why does it output `false`? According to the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ContainsRune), it says:

> ContainsRune returns true if the Unicode code point r is within s.

It seems to me that the code point is there, it seems strange that it would give `false` as a response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"\x0a" is not a unicode code point.

```
fmt.Println(strings.ContainsRune("\u00a0", '\u00a0'))
```

Works, as expected.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. It's strange, outputting `'\xa0'` gives correct output (a non-breaking space).

Comment: @robbrit '\xa0' is a valid code point - a non-breaking space. It is "\xa0" that is not a valid UTF-8 string. '\xa0' will be "\xc2\xa0" when UTF-8 encoded. Try: `fmt.Print([]byte(string('\xa0')))`

Comment: @ANisus bingo.  Good break down.

Comment: @ANisus Ah, that explains it. I guess I was assuming that when you put the rune in hex it actually showed the proper UTF-8 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

Because it's not a valid unicode code point, looking at [`strings.IndexRune`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/strings/strings.go?s=3966:4002#L180)

```
func IndexRune(s string, r rune) int {
    switch {
    case r < 0x80:
        .....
    default:
        .....
    }
    return -1
}
```

If you try `utf8.ValidString("\xa0")` it will return false.

Comment: Worthy of an +1 here.  Good idea checking IndexRune.